# Why does jQuery repeater's add button not working when I try to placed it on tr td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery.repeater

I am using https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater (jQuery repeater) to repeat the form field.

The <kbd>Add</kbd> button is not working, however, `delete is working fine`

```js
$('.repeater').repeater();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<table class="repeater">
  <tbody data-repeater-list>
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value=" ">-- Select --</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">One</option>
          <option value="3">One</option>
          <option value="4">One</option>
          <option value="5">One</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />

</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inquisitive_stha/jy86eu1o/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your table with `<form>` tag and use `<form>` tag `class`.  In your case:

```js
$('.repeater').repeater();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>

<form class="repeater">
  <table class="repeater1">
    <tbody data-repeater-list>
      <tr data-repeater-item>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value=" ">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">One</option>
            <option value="3">One</option>
            <option value="4">One</option>
            <option value="5">One</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />

  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to include the <kbd>Add</kbd> within `data-repeater-list` as below and it will work.

```js
$('.repeater').repeater();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<table class="repeater">


  <tbody data-repeater-list>
    <tr>
      <td><input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value=" " >-- Select --</option>
          <option value="1" >One</option>
          <option value="2" >One</option>
          <option value="3" >One</option>
          <option value="4" >One</option>
          <option value="5" >One</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    
  </tbody>
  

</table>
```

Comment: The "Add" shouldn't be duplicated; you can delete all the elements and have no way to recreate them!

Comment: Thanks for Correcting me. I have modified code, Please check the below [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8dm5cuL/) link

Comment: Looks good, now copy-past the code of JSFiddle in your post by [edit]ing it.